# Laravel policy does not authorize action

Tags: laravel, policy

In my Laravel application, I have several policies working, but one will not work.

Controller

```
    public function store(Project $project, CreateActionRequest $request)
{
    $this->authorize('store',  $project);

    Action::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('projects.show', $project->id)->withSuccess('Massnahme erfolgreich gespeichert');
}
```

Policy

```
namespace App\Policies\Project;
use App\Models\Project\Project;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Project\Action;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
class ActionPolicy
{
use HandlesAuthorization;

public function store(User $user, Project $project)
{
    return $user->company_id === $project->company_id;
}
}
```

AuthServiceProvider

```
    protected $policies = [
    'App\Models\User' => 'App\Policies\CompanyAdmin\UserPolicy',
    'App\Models\Company' => 'App\Policies\CompanyAdmin\CompanyPolicy',
    'App\Models\Team' => 'App\Policies\CompanyAdmin\TeamPolicy',
    'App\Models\Department' => 'App\Policies\CompanyAdmin\DepartmentPolicy',
    'App\Models\Location' => 'App\Policies\CompanyAdmin\LocationPolicy',
    'App\Models\Division' => 'App\Policies\CompanyAdmin\DivisionPolicy',
    'App\Models\Costcenter' => 'App\Policies\CompanyAdmin\CostcenterPolicy',
    'App\Models\Workplace' => 'App\Policies\CompanyAdmin\WorkplacePolicy',
    'App\Models\Product' => 'App\Policies\CompanyAdmin\ProductPolicy',
    'App\Models\Project\Action' => 'App\Policies\Project\ActionPolicy',
    'App\Models\Project\Project' => 'App\Policies\Project\ProjectPolicy',
];
```

CreateActionRequest

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Project;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateActionRequest extends FormRequest
{

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}


public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
    ];
}
}
```

All policies are working except ActionPolicy and ProjectPolicy. I added in the policy a `__construct()` method to check if the policy is called. But ActionPolicy and ProjectPolicy are not working. How can I search the error? I tried with `dd()` but I always got the message:

> This action is unauthorized

Comment: Show us the code from `CreateActionRequest`

Comment: Your `CreateActionRequest` looks fine, even tho you are not using `Action Policy` inside because you are returning `true` as if users are always authorized, so the problem is not in your `CreateActionRequest`, you'll need to post the error stacktrace from `laravel.log` on some `pastebin` and then update your question with a link

Comment: @NikolaGavric: There is no message in the laravel.log regarding this error.

Comment: The problem is not in your `CreateActionRequest` nor in your `Action Policy` from what I can see, can you confirm that you are sending `name` attribute with at least 3 letters inside of your `store` and confirm that is the method where you get `unauthorized`?

Comment: If i disable the `$this->authorize('store',  $project);` the input is stored without problems. The fields from the form:
https://pastebin.com/raw/2kyD40Qn

Comment: I see where the error is now :D I will create an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are injecting `CreateActionRequest` instead of `Request` that means you are defining your own set of rules to authorize the `FormRequest` which comes inside of your method. Further it means that you gotta define a few rules which the "`FormRequest`" has to pass in order to EVEN reach your controller, this is a nice concept that I like about Laravel since the code is not centralized, but rather spread and every layer has it's own responsibility. Now, you don't have to call any method from your `CreateActionRequest` nor you have to write any code regarding that class in your controller, because Laravel runs `authorize` method by `default` before allowing the `Request` to reach your controller, before running `authorize`method in your `CreateActionRequest` it runs `rules` method which verifies that all the given fields pass the expressions you assigned them, so the execution is something like this `CreateActionRequest => rules => authorize => IF(authorized) Controller ELSE Not authorized`, hope that makes sense. In order to fix your code:

1.) Remove `$this->authorize('store',  $project);`

This will allow you to pass `not authorized` error in case your `name` passes the truth test inside of `rules` method inside of your `CreateActionRequest`. If you wish to utilize your `Action Policy` you will need to hook up your custom `Request`(CreateActionRequest) with it and this is how:

```
public function authorize()
{
    $store = $this->route('project');
    //The above line will return Project object if your mapping is correct
    //If it's not it will return the value you passed to your route for {project}
    return $this->user() && $this->user()->can('store', $store);
}
```

**EDIT:**

[Here is the link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#authorizing-form-requests) where you can see how to properly authorize and connect policy with `CreateActionRequest`

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. What is strange for me, i have in the same application 10 models with the same concept. They are working perfectly. So i will create a new model from scratch and check, if there is something different.

Comment: It's giving you the same error when just removing `$this->authorize` from your controller?

Comment: When  I only remove the `$this->authorize`it works perfectly. What i saw, that in the procedure i showed, the debugbar gate it's empy. But with your solution, it returns a lot of info (project) but result still false.

Comment: Well with removing `$this->authorize` from controller and without changing your code for `authorize` method inside `CreateActionRequest` you will be authorized, but read my answer again and lookup `authorizing form requests` I've put a link inside of my answer which will help you to `implement` your `policy` correctly

Comment: Thanks for you help. Now it's working. But i have to setup the rules in ProjectPolicy, not in ActionPolicy. But I still not understand, why the other models are working correctly!

Comment: Can you repeat where you need what Policy?

Comment: Post your routes too and explain to me briefly, what you wanna do

Comment: I have existing projects and i like to add a action to a project. Because it's a multiuser solution, i have to check if the user is related to the same company like the project. So the `$user->company_id' must be the same like the `$project->company_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all your controller methods defined with the `Request` object last?

```
public function store(Project $project, CreateActionRequest $request)
```

The `Request` object should be the first parameter in the methods signature:

```
public function store(CreateActionRequest $request, Project $project)
```

> **Dependency Injection & Route Parameters**
>
> If your controller method is also expecting input from a route parameter you should list your route parameters after your other dependencies.

Most Laravel authorization mechanisms have identical method signatures allowing them to work across varying classes.

Comment: No,  had only this one in the wrong order. I changed it but the result is still the same.